# Hudson Get Current Working Directory (MSBuild)

Tags: hudson

I'm trying to set the Outdir for a MSBUILD task on Hudson. How can I include the working directory environment value?

[image: Screen Shot Hudson]

Answer (score 0):

I've located the variable in order to include the working directory environment.

The variable is:

`%WORKSPACE%`

This has resolved the issue.